# FlexBox container not flexible height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers

I am in the process of working on my portfolio and I faced an issue where the text inside the about section is not increasing the height of the container dynamically. whenever the user resizes for example.

Here's my code.

```css
/* === GLOBAL === */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
/* === SIDEBAR === */

#sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
#sidebar > a {
  display: none;
  /* Hiding The Anchor Element (The Logo) On Desktops */
}
#sidebar h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#sidebar p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: .40em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#sidebar p a {
  color: #8e44ad;
}
#sidebar p a:hover {
  color: #e67e22;
}
#sidebar > ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}
#sidebar > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
}
#sidebar > ul li a:hover {
  color: #e67e22;
}
#sidebar nav {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
#sidebar nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
#sidebar nav ul li {
  padding: .5em;
}
#sidebar nav ul li a::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
#sidebar nav ul li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
/* === CONTENT === */

#content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
#about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E0E4CC;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#about h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
#about p {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 2em 8em;
  line-height: 1.8;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Average";
}
#expertise {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7BB0A6;
}
#recent-works {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #523D1F;
}
#contact {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6766;
}
footer {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Saad Al-Sabbagh | Web Developer</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Average|Oswald:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Sidebar Wrapper -->
  <div id="sidebar">
    <a href="#">S</a>

    <h1>Saad Al-Sabbagh</h1>
    <p>Front-End Developer
      <br>and Author @ <a href="#">SitePoint</a>
    </p>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-telegram"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#expertise">Expertise</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#recent-works">Recent Works</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- Content Wrapper -->
  <div id="content">

    <!-- About -->
    <section id="about">
      <h2>About</h2>

      <p>Hi, I'm Saad (Sa'ad), a front-end developer from Kirkuk (Northern Iraq). I'm also an avid problem solver, blogger and UX designer I write about design on SitePoint, and about everything else on my Blog!
        <br>
        <br>I am a firm believer in self-learning and that everything can be learned through hard work, and this generally helps me increase my knolwedge on various topics and add new stuff into my repertoire everyday.
        <br>
        <br>I'm currently available for hire or take on freelance work. Feel free to browse through my expertise, recent works, and do not hesitate to contact me!</p>
    </section>

    <!-- Expertise -->
    <section id="expertise">

    </section>

    <!-- Recent Works -->
    <section id="recent-works">

    </section>

    <!-- Contact -->
    <section id="contact">

    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>

    </footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex: 0 0 0` on `#about`

like:

```
#about {
  background-color: #e0e4cc;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
```

}

```css
/* === GLOBAL === */
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: flex;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

/* === SIDEBAR === */
#sidebar {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 30vw;

 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;

 background-color: #27ae60;
}

#sidebar > a {
 display: none; /* Hiding The Anchor Element (The Logo) On Desktops */
}

#sidebar h1 {
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: "Oswald";
 font-size: 3.2rem;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}

#sidebar p {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: .40em;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#sidebar p a {
 color: #8e44ad;
}

#sidebar p a:hover {
 color: #e67e22;
}

#sidebar > ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.8em;
 margin-top: .5em;
}

#sidebar > ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: .5em;
}

#sidebar > ul li a:hover {
 color: #e67e22;
}

#sidebar nav {
 margin-top: 3em;
}

#sidebar nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 1em;
}

#sidebar nav ul li {
 padding: .5em;
}

#sidebar nav ul li a::after {
 content: " ";
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

#sidebar nav ul li a:hover::after {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}

/* === CONTENT === */
#content {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 70vw;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 overflow: auto;
}

#about {
  background-color: #e0e4cc;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
   }

#about h2 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-family: "Oswald";
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 2.5rem;
}

#about p {
 align-self: center;
 padding: 2em 8em;
 line-height: 1.8;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: "Average";
}

#expertise {
 height: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #7BB0A6;
}

#recent-works {
 height: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #523D1F;
}

#contact {
 height: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FF6766;
}

footer {
 height: 20%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Saad Al-Sabbagh | Web Developer</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Average|Oswald:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 </head>

 <body>

  <!-- Sidebar Wrapper -->
  <div id="sidebar">
   <a href="#">S</a>

   <h1>Saad Al-Sabbagh</h1>
   <p>Front-End Developer <br>and Author @ <a href="#">SitePoint</a></p>

   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-telegram"></a></li>
   </ul>

   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#expertise">Expertise</a></li>
     <li><a href="#recent-works">Recent Works</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- Content Wrapper -->
  <div id="content">

   <!-- About -->
   <section id="about">
    <h2>About</h2>

    <p>Hi, I'm Saad (Sa'ad), a front-end developer from Kirkuk (Northern Iraq). I'm also an avid problem solver, blogger and UX designer I write about design on SitePoint, and about everything else on my Blog! <br><br>

    I am a firm believer in self-learning and that everything can be learned through hard work, and this generally helps me increase my knolwedge on various topics and add new stuff into my repertoire everyday. <br><br>

    I'm currently available for hire or take on freelance work. Feel free to browse through my expertise, recent works, and do not hesitate to contact me!</p>
   </section>

   <!-- Expertise -->
   <section id="expertise">

   </section>

   <!-- Recent Works -->
   <section id="recent-works">

   </section>

   <!-- Contact -->
   <section id="contact">

   </section>

   <!-- Footer -->
   <footer>

   </footer>

  </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: For some reason that completely collapsed the section, now #about is not showing up and it has no height.

Comment: Use `flex: 0 0 100%` on `#about` and let me know.

Comment: It kinda did. The #about is now back and it increased the section to the full length of the document I used 80% instead of 100% and it still doesn't expand when I resize the window. And no scrollbars are being shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `display:flex` property usually you don't have to set explicitly the width and height of the div, in your case the div `#content`. So just remove `height: 100vh` from this div.

```css
/* === GLOBAL === */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
/* === SIDEBAR === */

#sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
#sidebar > a {
  display: none;
  /* Hiding The Anchor Element (The Logo) On Desktops */
}
#sidebar h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#sidebar p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: .40em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#sidebar p a {
  color: #8e44ad;
}
#sidebar p a:hover {
  color: #e67e22;
}
#sidebar > ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}
#sidebar > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
}
#sidebar > ul li a:hover {
  color: #e67e22;
}
#sidebar nav {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
#sidebar nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
#sidebar nav ul li {
  padding: .5em;
}
#sidebar nav ul li a::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
#sidebar nav ul li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
/* === CONTENT === */

#content {
  width: 70vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
#about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E0E4CC;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#about h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
#about p {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 2em 8em;
  line-height: 1.8;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Average";
}
#expertise {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7BB0A6;
}
#recent-works {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #523D1F;
}
#contact {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6766;
}
footer {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Saad Al-Sabbagh | Web Developer</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Average|Oswald:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Sidebar Wrapper -->
  <div id="sidebar">
    <a href="#">S</a>

    <h1>Saad Al-Sabbagh</h1>
    <p>Front-End Developer
      <br>and Author @ <a href="#">SitePoint</a>
    </p>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-telegram"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#expertise">Expertise</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#recent-works">Recent Works</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- Content Wrapper -->
  <div id="content">

    <!-- About -->
    <section id="about">
      <h2>About</h2>

      <p>Hi, I'm Saad (Sa'ad), a front-end developer from Kirkuk (Northern Iraq). I'm also an avid problem solver, blogger and UX designer I write about design on SitePoint, and about everything else on my Blog!
        <br>
        <br>I am a firm believer in self-learning and that everything can be learned through hard work, and this generally helps me increase my knolwedge on various topics and add new stuff into my repertoire everyday.
        <br>
        <br>I'm currently available for hire or take on freelance work. Feel free to browse through my expertise, recent works, and do not hesitate to contact me!</p>
    </section>

    <!-- Expertise -->
    <section id="expertise">

    </section>

    <!-- Recent Works -->
    <section id="recent-works">

    </section>

    <!-- Contact -->
    <section id="contact">

    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>

    </footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the issue still persists. :(

Comment: @SaadAl-Sabbagh Sry, my bad, I meant the div #content not #container, but yeah great that you could have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I removed the height from each of the containers inside #content.